# How do I get the six vertices for a clickable poly?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand how a [color picker](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp) works.

Run the following code, the poly at the upper left corner is clickable.

```html
<div><img style="margin-right:2px;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyNvx.gif" 
        usemap="#colormap" alt="colormap" data-pinit="registered">
    </div>
    <map id="colormap" name="colormap">
        <area style="cursor:pointer" shape="poly" coords="63,0,72,4,72,15,63,19,54,15,54,4">
    </map>
```

The only thing I don't understand is this line of code.

```
coords="63,0,72,4,72,15,63,19,54,15,54,4"
```

I guess it gives some kind of boundaries of that poly,
e.g (63,0) is one of the six vertices of it.

Do I have to generate those manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed generate those 126 `area` elements using a script. The hexagons have specific metrics:

- their vertical sides have a height of 11 pixels
- their slanted sides have a height of 4 pixels and a width of 9 pixels.

This means that two horizontally neighbouring hexagons have an x-coordinate difference of 18 pixels, and two consecutive rows of hexagons have a y-coordinate difference of 15 pixels.

Here is a demo of how to generate those `area` elements dynamically. It also includes a click handler that will log the sequence number of the area that was clicked:

```js
let colormap = document.querySelector("map");
let html = '';
for (let y = 0; y < 195; y += 15) {
    let margin = Math.abs(6 - y / 15) * 9;
    for (let x = margin; x < 225 - margin; x += 18) {
        let coords = [x+9, y, x+18, y+4, x+18, y+15, x+9, y+19, x, y+15, x, y+4];
        html += `<area style="cursor:pointer" shape="poly" coords="${coords}">\n`;
    }
}

colormap.innerHTML = html;

let span = document.querySelector("span");
let areas = [...colormap.children]; 
colormap.addEventListener("click", e => {
    span.textContent = areas.indexOf(e.target);
});
```

```css
div { display: flex }
```

```html
<div>
    <img style="margin-right:2px;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyNvx.gif" 
        usemap="#colormap" alt="colormap" data-pinit="registered">
    <span></span>
</div>
<map id="colormap" name="colormap">
</map>
```